# Ideal ignition temperature for a D-T plasma fusion reaction

Tags: plasma-physics, fusion

I've been trying to calculate the ideal ignition temperature for a 50-50% Deuterium-Tritium (D-T) reaction. In the literature this value is $4.4$keV and I'm getting $5.2$keV. Here's how I'm carrying out my calculations.

This value can be calculated by making the alpha particle heating, $S_{\alpha}=(1/4)n^2 E_{\alpha}\langle \sigma v \rangle$, equal to the Bremsstrahlung losses, $S_B=C_B n^2 \sqrt{T}$:

$$S_{\alpha}=S_B \Leftrightarrow E_{\alpha}\langle \sigma v \rangle-4C_B \sqrt{T}=0$$

The value I get for $C_B=(\sqrt{2}/3\pi^{5/2})(e^6/(\varepsilon_0^3 c^3 h m_e^{3/2})$ is $4.22\cdot10^{-29}$ $\sqrt{kg}\, m^4\, s^{-2}$, where $e$ is the electron charge, $\varepsilon_0$ the vacuum permittivity, $h$ Planck's constant and $m_e$ the electron mass. The alpha particle energy is $E_{\alpha}=3.5$keV. For the reactivity, $\langle \sigma v \rangle$, which is a function of $T$, I have been using two equations: one derived analytically and another from a fit.

The analytical expression I'm using is the following (from Plasma Physics and Fusion Energy book by J.P. Freidberg, 2007):

$$ \langle \sigma v \rangle = \frac{4 \sigma_m}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{\frac{2T_m}{m_r}} \left(\frac{T_m}{T}\right)^{2/3}e^{-3(T_m/T)^{1/3}+2} $$

Where $\sigma_m = 5.03$barns and $T_m = 296$keV. $m_r$ is the reduced mass of the deuterium and tritium, which is given by $m_r=(m_D m_T)/(m_D + m_T)$, where $m_D=2.0141u$, $m_T=3.01605u$ and $u=1.660\cdot 10^{-28}$kg.

From a dimensional analysis, I have defined the factor $c_f=1000 e$ to transform keV into Joule. Then, I  multiplied the reactivity $\langle \sigma v \rangle$ by $\sqrt{c_f}$ in order to set the units in $m^3 s^{-1}$ (because $T_m$ is in keV). I also multiplied the constant $C_B$ by this value due to the $\sqrt{T}$ on the tempertaure, which gives $\sqrt{c_f} C_B = 5.34\cdot 10^{-37}$. Finally, I multiplied $E_{\alpha}$ by $c_f$. Which explicity gives:

$$S_{\alpha}=S_B \Leftrightarrow c_f E_{\alpha}\langle \sigma v \rangle-4C_B \sqrt{c_fT}=0$$

$$ \langle \sigma v \rangle = \frac{4 \sigma_m}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{c_f\frac{2T_m}{m_r}} \left(\frac{T_m}{T}\right)^{2/3}e^{-3(T_m/T)^{1/3}+2} $$

By doing this and solving the first equation I get that the temperature is $5.2$keV instead of the $4.4$keV in the literature.

Can someone help me to troubleshoot what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: the temperature $T$ in the reactivity, $\langle \sigma v \rangle$, has the term $k_B$ (Boltzmann's constant) abosrbed into it, hence being expressed in keV.